# Trying to find Italian village

Tags: italy

When we were in Italy about 20 years ago, we visited this beautiful old walled city, and I'm hoping to track it down for an upcoming visit.  Unfortunately, I can't find any of my photos from the visit, and even at the time I don't think we knew what the name was.  I'm hoping I can give enough details for a local to help me find it again ...

What we do remember is this: we were on the Autostrada from Naples, heading towards Venice.  We were on the E35 because we skirted Rome, but we weren't going to see Florence.  We stayed on toll roads for a few more hours, then exited.  The town we encountered first was reasonably sized, but only had a few major roads going through and was having a big festival so traffic was a mess.  We ended up leaving the town and driving through olive tree orchards for a while on a little (barely 2-lane) road.  We encountered no other towns or villages for close to an hour as the road started to climb and got windy with beautiful views from hillsides.  Eventually we came around a corner and were faced with a curving city wall on our right with parking spaces and a bunch of old men sitting in chairs watching the world go by.  We figured there had to be a restaurant so we parked and walked through the gate, cheerfully saying "Buonasera" (one of our few Italian words) to everyone.  Through the gate was a single street, two streets at the most, and a few delivery vans so you could tell cars could get in, but nobody parked inside the walls, there wasn't room.  The street was lined with 2- or 3-story apartments and all the old women came out to stare at us.  We got to the end of the street which was also the end of the village as we were at the top of a rather steep cliff, and there was only a stairway leading down to the bottom of the valley (and nothing to see down there).  So we walked back out the street, got in the car, and kept going along the road we were on.  Around the corner on the left we found a restaurant and a gas station.

I know that's more prose than useful details, but again I'm hoping someone familiar with the area can suggest some possibilities, I'm thinking that if I see it on Google Maps I might recognize it!

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: The distance from the big town to the walled town may have been much shorter than an hour, we were hungry and really low on gas so it may have just felt like an hour ... and if it helps, we were there in early June, perhaps the first weekend.

Comment: And when we got off the autostrada, we weren't right in the town - it took a few minutes to get from the autostrada to the town, but not more than 10 minutes to the center of the town.

Comment: I could bet that the larger town was Foligno and the rustic village was Spello, but that's only a guess (owing to the cuisine there). There are so many!

Comment: Thanks for the idea Gayot!  Unfortunately, those two villages are too close together, and Spello is much too large. We're scrounging through boxes of travel souvenirs to see if we have anything that might shed light on this ...

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is "too broad".  It's limited to a specific problem, there is quite a bit of detail, and I'm not asking multiple questions.

Comment: A required number of members with voting privileges deemed it such. HOWEVER, if you think the decision is unfair or should otherwise be examined by the higher-ups, you can post a complaint/enquiry on META. And they will make a ruling (which might be in your favour!)  http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BettyCrokker I didn't vote to close but the question seems to be something of a wild goose chase to me. There are many, many possible answers and there's no real way that an answerer can know if they've found the right one. Essentially, all people can do is post a big list of guesses and you can look at the various places on Google maps to see if they look right. Maybe "too broad" isn't exactly the right close reason, but I don't think this question is a good fit for the site.